# Does Carthage supports static library in Swift 4?

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, swift4, ios-frameworks, carthage

After release of Swift 4, Xcode supporting Static library as dependency.
I am adding Static lib as dependency for dynamic framework.
But it show below error:

```
*** Skipped building poc_objc_static_lib due to the error:
Dependency "poc_objc_static_lib" has no shared framework schemes
```

I have one Static library with shared schema but Carthage fails to build it from checkout.

So I am confuse that , might be Carthage not supporting for Static library yet.

If it supporting, then Is there any configuration required for Static lib to build using Carthage ?

==> Dynamic Framework ==> Static lib as dependency(Using Carthage)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently Carthage only supports building dynamic frameworks. Damir's answer references the ability to build a dynamic framework as a static one (https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/StaticFrameworks.md)

What you are looking for (Carthage to build static swift frameworks which are now supported in Swift 4/Xcode 9.3) is in progress, see here: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/pull/1935

Answer (score 0):

Your scheme is static library not a static framework. Carthage only supports building frameworks. Static framework support is semi-official. Documented [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/StaticFrameworks.md).